# Post to two different methods from single form

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form with user name and password. Once I click on the submit button, I want to post to two different PHP methods at two different servers. How can this be done? Can this be done using HTML form? Or should I use JavaScript? Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following code but it is not working. Where am I wrong here? Thank you in advance..!

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title id="login_form">Login Form testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

         $('#loginform').submit(function(){
               $("form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) { 
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submission behavior
      var data = $(this).serialize(); // gather data from the form and serialize it
      $.post('URL_1', data, successAction1); // post it to destination 1
      $.post('URL_2', data, successAction2); // post it to destination 2
 });

 var successAction1 = function() { alert("Success one");};
 var successAction2 = function() { alert("Success two");};


});
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form id="loginform" action="">
<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />

<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</fieldset>
</form>
        </body>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why not post to 1 server, and send the part of the data that is to go elsewhere from there

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Maybe his host does not allow server-side scripting?

Comment: @Mr47: What host doesn't allow that? There are free hosts that support an array of server-side scripting. Host the form in an iFrame if you have to. Processing forms is _always_ best done away from the client

Comment: There are two servers with two HTML forms. I need to log in to both by entering usernames and passwords only in one form.I can send username and password from one form to its PHP server. How can this same information be sent to other server's login form so that I can log in to both servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could post it using AJAX with eg. [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) library:

```
 $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) { // listen to form submission (use whatever selector suits you, but make sure it is the form itself)
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submission behavior
      var data = $(this).serialize(); // gather data from the form and serialize it
      $.post('URL_1', data, successAction1); // post it to destination 1
      $.post('URL_2', data, successAction2); // post it to destination 2
 });

 var successAction1 = function() { /*what to do after 1st post*/};
 var successAction2 = function() { /*what to do after 2nd post*/};
```

I'd suggest reading the api documentation about [$.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this can be done, but you're going to need some javascript.

Assuming this is your form:

```
<form id="#login">
  <p>
   <label>
     Username:
     <input type="text" name="username" />
   </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      Password:
      <input type="password" name="password" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Then this JavaScript will get you started:

```
$('#login').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stops the normal functionality of the form
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://website1.com',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: (data) {
      // do whatever
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://website2.com',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: (data) {
      // do whatever
    }
  });
});
```

You'll need jQuery installed on your page for this solution to work.

Checkout http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more detail on query ajax.

Also If you are indeed posting to different websites with different domain names you're going to run into a Cross-origin problem. Solution here is to use CORS. Which you will find many solutions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript onclick function and call two function. use ajax